# Ubuntu 11.0 won't boot up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, boot-failure

Long story, but it began on windows 7. It would slow down, then freeze, then crash. I would restart the computer, and sometimes it would say "no OS detected", so I recovered it. When I did that, I was still running into problems, so I just loaded Ubuntu as a dual boot. When I did this, my computer ran smoothly, and I didn't have a single problem, until I shut it off. Now, windows 7 is non-existent, and Ubuntu won't boot. It gives me an option to go into recovery, but when I get there, it won't finish booting. It gives a few lines of errors, and gives me something of a command terminal which says (initramfs). Most codes such as "sudo" or "exit" will not do anything, in fact, my computer freezes when I type exit.

When I set up a dual boot, I used the setup menu that ubuntu gave me. I'm not exactly sure which version I'm running, only that it is somewhat current. Help would be much appreciated, even if your advice is to get a new computer. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds as if you have a failing hard drive. boot a live CD and check the hard drive. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-find-out-if-harddisk-failing.html

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...Something is failing in your computer. Try  this:

Burn a Live CD or USB drive of 11.10. Once it's burned, boot into the live version of Ubuntu. Once you're into Ubuntu, open the app "System Testing". Run the tests, and see if something fails. If a test fails, you will know what component is failing. It might also be a good time to recover data, if you have not already. If the Live CD/DVD doesn't boot, it is not the hard drive that is failing.

Hope this helps!